# How to add more field names to query board view in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Hi we have queries created for customised identity fields on Azure WIs and I would like to know how to add more fields to this board view under queried data. By default it only shows the title and the assigned to fields of a work item.

[image]

I tried Settings for the current query board view, there's no option to add a custom field to this view of a card.

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom extension: [Query Based Boards](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.EdTro-AzureDevOps-Extensions-QueryBasedBoards-Public). There is no visible setting for additional fields. You may add your request here: https://github.com/edtro/EdTro.AzureDevOps.Extensions.querybasedboards/issues